# stop anchor from redirecting when dynamically setting href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor on my page which looks like this: `<a id="login" href="login.php"></a>`

However, when a user inputs data in the page, in order that he shouldn't lose that data when going to the login page (the data can be saved without being logged in), I change it by taking out the href and adding an onclick to warn the user, as follows:

```
if (-code which checks for user input-){
        $('#login').attr('href','javascript:void(0)');$('#login').attr('onclick','logincheck()');
        }
function logincheck(){
alert("Going to the login page will make you lose your work. If you want to save them to a collection, please do so now. When you're ready, click the login button again."); 
$('#login').attr('onclick','');$('#login').attr('href','login.php');
}
```

So the user gets the warning, and now the he can click the login button again to login.

The problem I'm having that for some reason the `$('#login').attr('href','login.php');`makes the page redirect right away. I'm guessing this is because the we're still in the middle of the anchor click.

How can I change this href but keep the page from actually redirecting before the button is clicked again? I tried adding `return false` but that didn't help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not consolidate it into a single item?

```
$('#login').on('click',function(e){
    if($(this).data('clicked')!=='true'){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Going to the login page will make you lose your work. If you want to save them to a collection, please do so now. When you're ready, click the login button again.");
        $(this).data('clicked','true');
    }
});
```

This will prevent the action the first time, provide the alert, and give it the `clicked` data to show it has been clicked. The second time it won't meet the `if` condition, and continue to login.

This avoids the `javascript:void(0)` bit, as well as any `onclick` attributes ... everything is contained in your JS file.

Answer (score 0):

You need `e.preventDefault();`

```
$('#login').on('click', function(e){
    if(!$(this).data('clicked')){
            $(this).data('clicked', true);
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Going to the login page will make you lose your work. If you want to save them to a collection, please do so now. When you're ready, click the login button again."); 
    }
});
```